# Postgres index most recent by foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have a table with a thousand users and 50 million user_actions.  A few users have more than a million actions but most have thousands.

```
CREATE TABLE users (id, name)
CREATE TABLE user_actions (id, user_id, created_at)
CREATE INDEX index_user_actions_on_user_id ON user_actions(user_id)
```

Querying `user_actions` by `user_id` is fast, using the index.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_actions 
WHERE user_id = ? 
LIMIT 1
```

But I'd like to know the *last* action by a user.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_actions 
WHERE user_id = ? 
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This query throws out the index and does a table scan, backwards until it finds an action.  Not a problem for users that have been active recently, too slow for users that haven't.

Is there a way to tune this index so postgres keeps track of the last action by each user?  (For bonus points the last N actions!)

Or, suggested alternate strategies?  I suppose a materialized view of a window function will do the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index on `(user_id, created_at)`

This will allow PostgreSQL to do a index scan to locate the first record.

This is one of the cases where multi-column indexes make a big difference.

Note we put user_id first because that allows us to efficiently select the sub-portion of the index we are interested in, and then from there it is just a quick traversal to get the most recent created_at date, provided not a lot of dead rows in the area.

Comment: might want to order that by desc as well depending on how the SQL is written

Comment: Maybe but you can scan an index forward or backward so not sure in this case if this query would care that much